# Is Flight Booking Is a Must For Uk Visit Visa?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

i want to know do i have to attach a flight booking confirmation with my uk visit visa application?

Is there any rules that can reject my visa if i wont attach flight reservation before getting my visa?

Comment: [The official list](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/documents-you-must-provide) is probably what you should read.

Comment: i heard somewhere that i have to show a flight itinerary with a verificable reservation code but unless i reserve it they(airlines) wont send me a reservation code ! thats why i am confused

Comment: See the linked duplicate. In short, it's not a "must", it's actually a "no-no". The UK government explicitly says you should not book anything before getting the visa.